# Why did my servo motor break when controlling it from a raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio, servo, gpiozero

I was trying to control a Tower Pro SG-5010 servo motor using a Raspberry Pi 4, with the
python code below, but after working for a minute or so, the servo started not turning for some of the commands, and now makes a clicking sound when it should be turning, but does not move at all. The servo is powered with a breadboard power supply through a 100 uF capacitor, and connected to the ground pin of the raspberry pi. This same code and wiring worked to power some continuous rotation servos I have, but not this regular servo. I don't have a multimeter or any fancy tools to measure voltage, current, etc. and I didn't notice any physical signs of damage to the servo.

Afterwords, I realised that `servo.value = None` isn't necessary for a regular servo, though I was using it for the continuous rotation ones, and wondered if it may have caused the problem.

I am very new to electronics and am not sure what caused my servo to break, or what I can do if I get a new one to prevent the same thing from happening.

```
from gpiozero import Servo
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep

factory = PiGPIOFactory()

servo = Servo(6, pin_factory=factory)

while True:
    servo.max()
    sleep(0.5)
    servo.min()
    sleep(0.5)
    servo.value = None
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: what is wrong with the servo?

Comment: @jsotola it no longer moves at all when I run the script, and makes a clicking sound

Comment: open it and figure out what is the problem

Comment: @jsotola I opened it and looked at the gears, and it looked like the motor itself was having trouble turning possibly? I don't really know anything about how servos work but it looked like the gears were fine

Comment: if you cannot figure out what is broken, then you cannot figure out what broke it ... maybe the servo simply failed

Comment: @jsotola I hope that this is the case. I just wanted to make sure since a newbie that I wasn't making any obvious mistakes.

Comment: I've run servos from a raspberry pi using python and it is very jittery. Because the raspberry pi operating system is busy running all kinds of operating system programs. Like a printer server. And python is a slow interpretive language. Some clam 100 to 1000 times slower then compiled languages such a C. So random clicking or small movements are to be expected. Use an Arduino if you want to get rid of the jitter. The difference between a continuous and normal servo? The continuous servo's speed changes while the normal servo's position changes. They both use similar pulse width controls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information supplied I would say you have forced the servo to move past its end stops.

Not all servos support pulse widths outside the range 1000 to 2000 µs.  Perhaps servo.max() and servo.min() are outside that range.